# deferred deep linking configure in ios

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links, deferred-deep-linking

I have configured deferred deep linking using Firebase dynamic URL. when I click the open button on the dynamic link preview page. it opens the app store and I can install the app. When I click the open button on the app store page app does not correctly open the page of the app. but when I click again open button is on the preview page. it correctly opens the page of the app. Could anyone have any idea about it?
mobile app is react native applicaion

Comment: As firebase mentioned in Step 8 in their [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/ios/receive),
In `application:openURL:options:` handle links received through your app's custom URL scheme. This method is called when your app is opened for the first time after installation.
If the Dynamic Link isn't found on your app's first launch, this method will be called with the DynamicLink's url set to nil, indicating that the SDK failed to find a matching pending Dynamic Link.

Comment: but after I installed the application.if I open the application using the dynamic link app correctly navigate

Comment: (https://yourdomain.page.link/?link=https://example.com/test?user%3D1qgknv&apn=org.example.com&isi=23432&ibi=org.example.com&cid=3233&_osl=https://yourpage.page.link/1232)
while i am installing the app, the preview page above the URL copy to the clipboard.  I pasted it somewhere and after I install the application then I click the URL it correctly navigated to the page. The only problem the open button in the app store does not navigate the application correctly